# 'this' in ember.js link-to helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to get hands-on experience with popular `ember.js` framework and quite amazed with lots of magical things.

One such is `this` in `link-to` handlebar helper which I couldn't digest.

Following is my code scenarios:

```
// handlebar script
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='products'>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <ul class='list-unstyled col-md-8'>
    {{#each}}
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <p>{{#link-to 'product' this class='btn btn-success' }}Buy for ${{price}}{{/link-to}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

// in app.js    
App.PRODUCTS = [
  {
    title: 'Chair',
    price: 99,
    description: 'Chair is...',    
  },
  ...
];    
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('products');
  this.resource('product', { path: '/products/:title'});  
});    
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.PRODUCTS;
  }
});
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {    
    return App.PRODUCTS.findBy('title', params.title);
  }
});
```

I came to know that `this` refers to `current product` in template but my questions are:

1. Does it interact with `App.ProductRoute` or `router`? If yes how?
2. Can we replace `this` with `this.title`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the `link-to` helper does. The `link-to` helper builds a URL based on the information you give it. Using the route name, it looks up the route defined in your router and uses the path that you specified. Then it uses the ID from the object to fill in the dynamic segment(s). It also makes sure to correctly fill in parent routes if necessary.
2. No, you need to use `this` because it needs the `id` to build the URL. You used to be able to pass in just `this.id`, but I don't think you can do that any more. (It's a bad idea anyway.) Also, Ember.js will use the object you pass it as the model for the route, thereby skipping the `model` hook in your `ProductRoute`. And the object you pass it can either be a fully-loaded model, or a promise of a model.

Comment: Does it search 'id' in my case particularly or use 'title' to fill in dynamic segment as my defined route is '/products/:title' ?

Comment: I did not see that you had `title` as a dynamic segment. Ember.js is always going to put IDs in the dynamic segment of a route. If you want to put something else there, you'd have to make it the ID of the model.